# ruby - syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN

Tags: ruby

The following is a portion of my code. Any advice is appreciated.

```
def how_many_guesses?
  guesses = 0
end

def guess 
  puts "Please type a number between 1 and a 100."
  gets.chomp
end

def correct?
  if guess == guess
    puts "You have already guessed this number, try again!"
    guess
  elsif guess == random_num
    you_are_correct
  elsif guess > correct_num
    puts "Too high!"
    how_many_guesses? += 1
    guess
  else
    puts "Too low!"
    how_many_guesses? += 1
    guess
  end
end
```

The error I received was:

```
syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN
    how_many_guesses? += 1
```

I don't understand what unexpected tOP_ASGN means.

Comment: what is random_num, correct_num, and what do you try to achieve anyway?

Answer (score 2):

As other commented you are trying to assign a value to a function.

You can use some other approaches for example using a class variable, or a setter method.

In the first case you use an instance variable, and you just increment or decrement its value:

```
class Guess

  def initialize
    @guesses = 0
  end

  def guess 
    puts "Please type a number between 1 and a 100."
    gets.chomp
  end

  def correct?
    if guess == guess
      puts "You have already guessed this number, try again!"
      guess
    elsif guess == random_num
      you_are_correct
    elsif guess > correct_num
      puts "Too high!"
      @guesses += 1
      guess
    else
      puts "Too low!"
      @guesses += 1
      guess
    end
  end
end
```

In this example you can use `attr_reader` to publish the `guesses` variable

The other way, more c++ style, is using getter and setter functions:

```
class Guess

  def initialize
    @guesses = 0
  end

  def get_guesses
    @guesses
  end

  def set_guesses(guesses)
    @guesses = guesses
  end

  def how_many_guesses?
    guesses = 0
  end

  def guess 
    puts "Please type a number between 1 and a 100."
    gets.chomp
  end

  def correct?
    if guess == guess
      puts "You have already guessed this number, try again!"
      guess
    elsif guess == random_num
      you_are_correct
    elsif guess > correct_num
      puts "Too high!"
      set_guesses(get_guesses + 1)
      guess
    else
      puts "Too low!"
      set_guesses(get_guesses + 1)
      guess
    end
  end
end
```

This is another solution, but it is not recommended in ruby.

EDIT: Some comments included the option of using global variables, just don't!

Answer (score 1):

how_many_guesses? is a function, you can only assign a value to a variable. But maybe you should read a bit more about functions generally, as your code indicates you might need some clarification.

What you probably wanted to do is something like:

```
$guesses = 0
```

and

```
$guesses += 1
```

You don't need a function here I think.

But the bigger problem will be that every time you wrote down "guess" it will wait for you to type a number.

```
  if guess == guess # here you'll enter 2 numbers
    puts "You have already guessed this number, try again!"
    guess # here you'll enter another one
  elsif guess == random_num # and if the 1st and 2nd numbers were different then you'll be asked another one here...
```

Comment: Why use global variable?

Comment: 'cause that would count it, and it looks like he tries to count the wrong guesses. Though it's very hard to guess from this code :(

Comment: Don't use global variables!

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @Gavriel's answer, functions are singletons, while += is an assignment operator

Your code can be rewritten to basically look like so:

```
def how_many_guesses?
  guesses = 0
end

how_many_guesses? = how_many_guesses? + 1
```

Which is impossible, as you can not assign to function symbols in this manner. It *is* possible to redefine a function on the fly due to Ruby's robust metaprogramming capabilities, but that falls far outside the scope of this question.

The easiest way for you to fix it is to do the following:

```
numGuesses = how_many_guesses?
numGuesses += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Replace all `how_many_guesses?` with `$guesses` making it a global variable. Define guesses at the top of the file: `$guesses = 0`

Option 2 (Better):

Put everything in a class and make `guesses` an instance variable:

```
class GuessGame
  def initialize
    @guesses = 0
  end

  def guess
    # ...
  end

  def correct?
    # ...
    @guesses += 1
  end
end
```